# The method 'fromSnapshot' isn't defined for the type 'Patient' dart flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, snapshot

trying to load data from firebase to a data table
i got this error :

> The method 'fromSnapshot' isn't defined for the type 'Patient'.

This is the function where i have this problem , it show on 'fromSnapshot'

```dart
Future loadMoreDataFromStream() async {
    final stream = collection.snapshots();

    stream.listen((snapShot) async {
      await Future.forEach(snapShot.docs, (DocumentSnapshot element) {
        final Patient data = Patient.fromSnapshot(element);
        if (!patients
            .any((element) => element.name == data.name)) {
          patients.add(data);
          addDataGridRow(data);
        }
      });

      updateDataGridDataSource();
    });
  }
```

and this is the class Patient that I call

```dart
class Patient{
  String? name ; 
  String? pass ; 
  String? image ; 
  String? genre ; 
  DateTime? birth ; 
Patient(this.name, this.pass, this.genre,this.birth,{this.reference});
DocumentReference? reference;
static fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Patient _newPatient = Patient.fromJson(snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>);
    _newPatient.reference = snapshot.reference;
    return _newPatient;}
factory Patient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) =>
      Patient(
          data['name'],
          data['pass'],
          data['birth'],
          data['genre'],);
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _patientToJson(this);
@override
String toString() => 'name $name';
Patient _patientFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Patient(
    json['name'],
    json['pass'],
    json['birth'],
    json['genre'],
  );}
Map<String, dynamic> _patientToJson(Patient instance) {
  return {
    'name' : instance.name,
    'pass': instance.pass,
    'birth': instance.birth,
    'genre': instance.genre,
  };}}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: you can see the full code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72546830/the-method-fromsnapshot-isnt-defined-for-the-type-patient-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a method instead:

```
static Patient fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Patient _newPatient = Patient.fromJson(snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>);
    _newPatient.reference = snapshot.reference;
    return _newPatient;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it dosen't work

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: the same error , nothings change

Comment: Are you importing the model from a different location? Can you provide a git repo with reproducible code?

Comment: yes , here is the source code https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/lazy-loading-in-flutter-data-table.aspx?ref=morioh.com&utm_source=morioh.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class looks something like this:

```
class Patient {
  String id = 'id'; //Add any other variable you want.

  Patient();

  factory Patient.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Patient newPatient = Patient.fromJson(snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>);
    newPatient.reference = snapshot.reference;
    return newPatient;
  }

}
```

Or this:

```
class Patient {
  String id; //Add any other variable you want.

  Patient({required this.id});

  factory Patient.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Patient newPatient = Patient.fromJson(snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>);
    newPatient.reference = snapshot.reference;
    return newPatient;
  }

}
```

Comment: I already described the constructor , if I let it empty or i put just one variable it causes error in others fuctions : here another part from my code Patient(this.name, this.pass, this.genre,
      this.birth, {this.reference});
DocumentReference? reference;
static fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    Patient _newPatient = Patient.fromJson(snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>);
    _newPatient.reference = snapshot.reference;
    return _newPatient;}
factory Patient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) => Patient(data['name'],data['pass'],data['birth'],data['genre'], );

Comment: Edit your question and post the class please.